# i am able to load only single section in a page using settimeout but page layout is destroyed during the process

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout

I wanted to load only div section in my header section of laravel 
blade but whenver i use setTimeout function of javascript to load that 
section  after setting inerval the layout of my page is in disarray.

I have tried settimeout and setinterval function but same issue happen again 
and and again.

header section

```
<li class="dropdown dropdown-notification nav-item" >
    <div id="reload1">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-label" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="ficon ft-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-default badge-danger badge-default badge-up badge-glow">{{$countNot}}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-media dropdown-menu right">
            <li class="dropdown-menu-header">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header m-0">
                    <span class="grey darken-2">Notifications</span>
                </h6>
                <span class="notification-tag badge badge-default badge-danger float-right m-0">{{$countNot}} New</span>
            </li>
            <li class="scrollable-container media-list w-100" >
                @foreach($userAll as $user)
                @if($user->notifications)
                @foreach ($user->notifications as $notification)
                @if(!$notification->read_at)
                <a href="{{route('show.order')}}">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left align-self-center"><i class="ft-plus-square icon-bg-circle bg-cyan"></i></div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h6 class="media-heading">You have new order!</h6>
                            <p class="notification-text font-small-3 text-muted">Order number is {{$notification->data['show']}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                @endif
                @endforeach
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-footer"><a class="dropdown-item text-muted text-center" href="javascript:void(0)">Read all
                notifications</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

timeout function to reload div

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
$('#reload1').load(location.href); },10000);
end function
```

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>   Query.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined